# Alta de imagenes en php ¿Cuales son los requisitos?

Tags: php, imagen, fileupload, upload

**Necesito un script para dar de alta una imagen.**
Sin embargo no lo logro.
Para ello hice lo siguiente:

```
if  (!empty($_FILES) && isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])) {

    $target_dir = "img/noticias/";
    $nombre_original = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

    $uploadOk = 1;

    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

/* ACA VAN UNAS VALIDACIONES QUE NO CONTROLAREMOS AHORA */

```
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "<br>Lamentablemente la imagen no fue dada de alta por un error desconocido.";

    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        echo "El nombre original: ".$nombre_original."<br>";
        $temp = explode(".", $nombre_original);
        //    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
        echo "El archivo se llamara: ".$newfilename."<br>";
        $target_file = $target_dir . $newfilename;
        echo "El archivo se guarda en: ".$target_file."<br>";
        echo "Fin.<br>";

        $tmp_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_file)) {
            echo "<br>Dar de alta a la base de datos.";
        }

        else {
            echo "<br>Lamentablemente la imagen no fue dada de alta: ".print_r(error_get_last())." <br>";

        }
    }
}else{echo 'El formulario nunca llego a destino.';}
```

Sin embargo, el script me devuelve lo siguiente:

> File is an image - image/jpeg.  El nombre original: mini_pic.jpg El
>   archivo se llamara: 1553108980.jpg El archivo se guarda en:
>   img/noticias/1553108980.jpg Fin.
>
> Lamentablemente la imagen no fue dada de alta: 1

Por ello, decidí agregar este código:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

echo '</br></br></br>';
echo 'El primer parametro es: '.$tmp_name.'</br>';
echo 'El segundo parametro es: '.$target_file.'</br>';
echo 'La funcion move_uploaded_files devuelve: </br>';
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_file);
```

Y ahora el script además me devuelve:

> El primer parametro es: mini_pic.jpg
>   El segundo parametro es:
>   img/noticias/1553108980.jpg La funcion move_uploaded_files devuelve:

Mi php_info incluye:

- file_uploads ON
- max_file_uploads 20
- upload_max_filesize 128M
- upload_tmp_dir NO VALUE
- post_max_size    128M

Asimismo, el directorio img/noticias/ SI EXISTE y hasta tiene algunos documentos en él.
Que me falta? no se que mas revisar.

Comment: Probablemente es cuestión de rutas; lo recomendable es usar rutas absolutas para evitar el problema. Revisa que el script para subir las imágenes está en el mismo directorio que **img**, yo creo que no.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby por responder. Intenté creando un directorio en donde está el script y aún así no solucioné nada. Tampoco logro un error_log o una excepción php clara para poder entender que es lo que no funciona.

Comment: podrias darle un `if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {
     echo "no existe esta ruta: {$target_dir}";   
}` para ver si es que alcanza la ruta correcta~